Inductance after core saturation
Looking at the datasheets of some drum core inductors, at higher currents the inductance drops significantly due to ferrite core saturation. But it seems inductance asymptotically approaches a value when the current is further increased. I attach inductance vs. current graph of 744045222 as an example. What is this value? Is this the inductance that we would measure if we remove the core from the component (effectively replacing it with air) but keep its coil shape?
This makes sense to me because as far as I know the slope of a magnetization curve drops to one after saturation. So, does that mean the relative permeability becomes one thus the inductor behaves like an air-core inductor?


Yes, this is generally correct. However inductors don't saturate 'suddenly' because the flux density inside the core may not be uniform (or, rarely, the core is not of uniform material). Thus as current increases, initially the highest flux density portions will saturate.
Some cores have significant losses from eddy currents. These act like small short circuits for induced currents and tend to reduce inductance - thus a poor quality core could have less inductance than an air cored one.

I feel like answering with an overly deep physical explanation today, so enjoy.  (If not to taste -- simply assume saturation is a thing that exists, and scroll below the cut.)
A workable model of magnetism is to say that the bulk material is divided into myriad microscopic domains, each of which is fully magnetized at whatever the total magnetic moment is for the material (which is to say, more or less Bsat, or a modest factor higher than this), and the orientations are random.  We can consider three cases:

Each domain has a fixed magnetization axis and magnitude -- perhaps aligned to the local crystal structure, but a domain could span multiple crystals as well (MnZn ferrites are in the spinel crystal family; the grain size is actually visible on some types e.g. Ferroxcube 3F3).  When an external field is applied, of sufficient strength, the entire domain flips, and becomes magnetized in the opposite direction: same axis, opposite polarity.
The domains are randomly oriented and fully magnetized, but their axes can vary.  Normally they are pointed randomly, but their direction can be influenced (maybe continuously, maybe suddenly) until they align with the applied field.
The domain boundaries themselves move around, so that perhaps (1) is true, but the effect is (2) because a neighboring more-favorably-pointed domain dominates under applied field.  Domain walls may also be subject to "pinning", where there are "hard" regions within the domain that make it harder for the domain walls to move.

Note that random magnets average out to zero in the bulk, so we can have a soft magnetic material made up of hard(ish) magnets like this, and still observe the overall behavior that we do.
I think the real case is a combination of all three, plus still other effects that I don't know about, and, that are just very hard to figure out in general because ferromagnetism is a wildly complicated phenomenon (it involves long-range order, so analytical approaches are inadequate, and you kind of have to simulate huge ensembles of little bits, and then you still aren't deriving average/bulk characteristics, you're curve-fitting to observations).
Anyway, when a magnetic field is applied, you can imagine, at first few (if any!) domains flip, twist or morph, relative to the field strength applied; that is, permeability (dB/dH) is low.  Most materials have low initial permeability, so this gives us a means to explain that already.  (Initial isn't what you asked about, of course!)  As field strength goes up, a large population of domains begins moving in response, and permeability goes up; eventually, the population shrinks again, or the amount of twist, or wall movement, runs out, and saturation ensues.  You can imagine saturation as all the domains pointing in the same direction, or as much as possible: the same actual direction if the axis rotates, otherwise for randomly-oriented domains, the maximum number of them are aligned parallel to the field, and those cross to it just don't count (in which case, we have a bulk Bmax of say 0.4T, but because ~1/π of them are pointed crosswise, it must be Bmax(domain) is actually 0.4π T or thereabouts).
The magnetization required to flip all those domains, or more closely approach all, is more-or-less inverse with the number of domains remaining to magnetize; or, if pointed cross-wise, both the sensitivity, and contribution (once flipped), of a given domain goes as the cosine of angle between applied field and domain axis; same effect in any case, permeability drops off hyperbolically, towards an asymptote of μ0.

Finally, the inductance curve you have, is the result of that bulk permeability factored down by the air gap of the drum core geometry.  This has a lot of air gap (about half the total length!), so μr is low, perhaps 2-20.  (I say "half", but mind that's length, and the cross-section through air can be much higher than through the core; this is why e.g. a simple rod can still have μr in the 10s, and squat drum/bobbin/spool shapes even more.)  In this case, we see L go from about 2200 to 400, or a ratio of 5.5, which seems quite reasonable.
Indeed, checking the part itself, we see the proportions are nearly square:

From: https://www.we-online.com/components/products/datasheet/744045222.pdf
Given the winding area is only about a mm tall, I might even put this in the "squat" class; I'm a little surprised μr isn't higher, but I've hardly done any calculations or testing with geometry like this, so the surprise is low.
There is further a geometric factor to saturation, where different parts of the core saturate at different rates; for example, in an E-core geometry, the inside corners saturate first (but are small, so easily go unnoticed, unless you need a very precise / linear component), and the outer corners saturate last (only once the inner path is well and fully saturated).  Or for a simpler case, consider a toroid: the inner loop paths have lower reluctance and thus higher flux density, so saturate faster than the outer paths.  A "thick" toroid (as might be used for ferrite beads or RF transformers, where high impedance per turn is needed more than large-signal linearity) might have a noticeable curve to its saturation figure.
It looks like saturation is pretty sudden here (almost sigmoidal, 90-10% over the say 100-150mA span), so whatever the exact geometry is, it seems they optimized it well, in terms of the active material all saturating at once, and the remaining material either being very small, or very irrelevant (the top/bottom plate parts don't do much without the central stem/cylinder joining them, so it may be that they aren't actually saturated, but have very little contribution anyway).
