Capacitor derating and half bridge driver follower low-pass filters


simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
If I use an X5R capacitor on the output filter stage of a variable output switching regulator (summarized above), how fast will the capacitor derating kick in assuming the regulator will only work in pulsed operation?
Derating here refers to the reduction in effective capacitance value of a ceramic capacitor due to a DC bias voltage comparable to that of its rated voltage: Derating,  (its lock-in mechanism).
I heard that derating is due to the "lock-in" of dipoles inside the dielectric of the capacitors.
Do they lock-in and derate the capacitance even for the 20% duty ratioed case of, say a 2ms pulsed operation repeated every 10ms?
Or, do they recover very quickly, and the capacitance won't be derated in these kinds of operations where we do have a DC component at the output but the operation is not constant, therefore allowing time for possible dipole recovery.
The circuit is not a simple DC supply; it is a time varying pulse generator. The shape of the pulse is encoded digitally using the PWM input but it is always non-negative. I wonder if the pulse will be distorted heavily compared to using a tantalum polymer capacitor there instead of a ceramic capacitor.
If the effect is significant, is there a simulation software that also accounts for derating of capacitors with voltage where I can test for this effect (I know that LTSpice has a voltage dependent capacitor defining capability by defining Q=f(V) as a function of voltage, this model may be insufficient)
In another note: This filter will surely behave non-linearly, right?   The cut-off frequency (initial target from LC filter \$1/(2\pi\sqrt{LC}) \approx 9 \text{ kHz}\$) change will be drastic at higher voltage outputs beyond ~10V average(?) value at output.
So, it is not wise to use a ceramic capacitor in these kinds of operations? Does that mean in this use case we have to go with tantalum polymer or aluminum electrolytic capacitors?
However, the low ESR of the ceramics still makes them attractive, right?

There's derating with applied DC voltage, variation of capacitance from datasheet specs due to the manufacturer specifying with (e.g. 0.5 V) AC bias vs. actual application, aging effects (see referee time), temperature variation and tolerance.  But ceramics are convenient, space-efficienct, cost effective and low ESR, so people put up with the negatives.

It's not clear what you're looking for here. You mention "derating" but do not explain its effect (as you understand it) in terms of circuit parameters (what's being derated, voltage? current? power?), and thus what consequence it would have on the design. We don't know what you're using the circuit for, so are unable to comment on any effects a ceramic capacitor may have (see above examples), and whether that will be important for your case. You don't simply describe it as a DC supply so I'm guessing it's not that, but that leaves many possibilities for what you're doing here.

@TimWilliams  I updated the question. Derating refers to the capacitance value derating.
Yes it is not a simple DC supply, it is a time varying pulse generator. The shape of the pulse is encoded digitally using the PWM input but it is always non-negative.   I wonder if the pulse will be distorted heavily compared to using a tantalum polymer capacitor there instead of a ceramic capacitor . They use ceramic capacitors in RF filters but those cases I see almost always have zero DC shift.

You may find this explanation of ferromagnetism relevant: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/715900/inductance-after-core-saturation/715910#715910 I don't know where you got the "lock-in" term from; the simple effect of the linked explanation is that, once a dipole's been moved (into a field-aligned state), it has no further contribution, which might be described as "locked", but this is not a term of the craft. The aggregate/bulk effect is well known however, and calling it "C reduction under DC bias", is most specific for circuit purposes.

Or just saying "C(V) curve", winking at the effect and making the implication of its common consequences.

Also, is there a reason why you must operate deep in the C(V) curve? Simply choosing large enough ceramics that the effect goes away (below some acceptable margin) obviates the concern entirely.

@TimWilliams "Simply choosing large enough ceramics" .   Here the concern is ceramics get quite expensive for large caps, I need a large capacitance there and I see that there are only X5R cap.s available at 22uF and no more for ceramic components.  Maybe the answer is using lots of them in parallel with X7R capacitors rated at >100V but the price gets ridiculous for single component solution, or the space occupied on the PCB also gets large if I parallel 22 cap.s of 1uF. Maybe the answer is the latter, using more of the higher voltage rated ones in parallel even if I have to use 10-20.

... When using the latter approach of using 22 pieces of 1uF capacitiors ( is this approach also commonly used in PCB designs?),  I also worry spreading so many of these components  may  hurt the desired  filter behavior even though it is operating sub-100KHz frequency ranges, the parasitics in between them and the effective ESR is going to be reduced a lot and the supplied pulse won't have a strong load driving capability ( due to complicated networks of series parasitics  increasing ESR and ESL)   @TimWilliams Thank you very much for the responses.

A sample filtering I used  and referred  to above on Digikey listings: https://www.digikey.com/short/v093w1pt     Sub-1$  22uF component solutions only entail X5R parts or worse.  For a higher  voltage-rated component, the price seems to go up somewhat exponentially in these ceramic capacitors.

"ceramics get quite expensive for large caps, I need a large capacitance there" -- right, so what other solutions might be considered? Examples: polymer or electrolytic types; phase-interleave inverter to reduce output ripple; higher Fsw to use less C.
